# Make AlertBox stay for a longer duration

Tags: android

Friends, I am using an alertbox in my app.

```
public static void Alertbox(String title, String mymessage,Context context) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setMessage(mymessage)

        .setCancelable(true)
        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {

            }
        }).show();
    }

    public static void ProcessDialogue(String title,Context context)
    {


    }
```

I am successfully implementing this code, but the issue is I am using it in following manner

```
Response.Alertbox(" ", "Thank You",this);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Tabs.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is the alertbox is shown for a very small duration.. many-a-times it happens that the Tabs activity is called & the alertbox message cannot be read also. Please help me with a way such that till Ok on alertbox is not pressed it must not navigate to the next activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate away on the click of the button, then put the navigation code in the `onclick` event.  You may also want to close the dialogue when the button is pressed.

```
public static void Alertbox(String title, String mymessage,Context context) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setMessage(mymessage)

    .setCancelable(true)
    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MyActvity.this,Tabs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            dismissDialog();
        }
    }).show();
}

public static void ProcessDialogue(String title,Context context)
{


}
```

And simply call the dialogue with

```
Response.Alertbox(" ", "Thank You",this);
```